# Less object is empty in react, webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, webpack-dev-server

In my React project I want to use less css modules.

My webpack config for css is:

```
{
            test: /\.(?:le|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                require.resolve('style-loader'),
                {
                    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                    options: {
                        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: () => [
                            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                            autoprefixer({
                                browsers: [
                                    '>1%',
                                    'last 4 versions',
                                    'Firefox ESR',
                                    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                ],
                                flexbox: 'no-2009',
                            }),
                        ],
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: require.resolve('less-loader'),
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
```

When I try to import `less` file `import css from './BotHeader.less'` the variable `css` is empty - `{}`. Why? Where is a problem?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here import styles from "./index.less";, change it on import styles from "./index.module.less"; and rename index.less to index.module.less, CRA uses module prefix for CSS modules

[github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/issues/421)

Comment: You need to review your question and add more details, otherwise no one will be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask